# How to get spring bean reference to java field automatically

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

my spring XML is below,

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />       
</bean>

<bean id="jTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

I'm creating the spring bean context when the server is starting up. When I hit on the submit button of the JSP page, it should call the servlet and executes the SQL Query.

Without doing `JdbcTemplate jTemplate = (JdbcTemplate)context.getBean("jTemplate")` is there anyway I can get the `jTemplate` object automatically injected to my java property?

my java property is this,

```
private JdbcTemplate jTemplate;
```

So, simply I want to use the `jTemplate` without just doing `JdbcTemplate jTemplate = (JdbcTemplate)context.getBean("jTemplate")`

Sorry guys I'm bit new to Spring, If you don't get what I'm saying please ask me again.

Comment: do you use any web framework like struts, wicket?

Answer (score 0):

Use autowiring which can be in three ways

1. By name
2. By Type
3. By Constructor

Further reading is available [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/beans.html)

like one solution is

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" autowire="byName">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<bean name="jTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Use `@Autowired` annotation to get this bean automatically like this.

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jTemplate;
```

Comment: @Kalhar, Thanks, but its not working, `jTemplate` object is null. my class shown below,

`public class SpringTest {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jTemplate;

    public String testMethod() throws SQLException {

 jTemplate.update("drop table if exists smoke;");
}
}`

Comment: Either you need to declare a bean <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" /> or just declare <annotation-driven /> element

Comment: also include `<context:component-scan base-package="your.package"/>` with `base-package` including the package of your class

Comment: @Kalher Please explain me more, how can I add that to my existing bean definition and use it..

Comment: Niranjan, yeah I have added the component scan, but I think it's there to define a class as a bean without using the XML bean definition. you need to add @Component also top of the class for this.

Comment: @user360321 Peruse this link http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html